# NPM does not work after NODE installation. Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run

Tags: node.js, npm

Didn't found strict answear of my issue so decided to create a new question.

I'm trying to install new instance of NODE and NPM to my PC. I get installation package from here:
https://nodejs.org/en/

After I accepted all steps installation was succesful. To verify what was installed form Power shell I chcecked installed version of the components:

```
    PS C:\Users\{myUserName}> node -v
    v14.18.1
    PS C:\Users\{myUserName}> npm -v
    Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: Cannot find fileAt line:1 char:1
    + npm -v
    + ~~~~~~.
    At line:1 char:1
    + npm -v
    + ~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Also I checked folder:
C:\Users{myUserName}\AppData\Roaming\npm

What's intresting this folder in empty.
Regarding "Environmental Variables" situation looks as below:
User variables - no NODE_PATH declaration
System variables - no NODE_PATH declaration, but I have PATH variable that include C:\Program Files\nodejs\

What is more "funny" after I install NODEJS package my CMD stop working and I cannot open it even after few restarts.

Does anyone can suggest any fix for that?

Answer (score 2):

Solution step by step:

1. Open Command Line or Power Shell terminal
2. Run this command:

   ```
   DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\RepairSource\Windows /LimitAccess
   ```
3. After it finishes (with success) run this command:

   ```
   sfc /scannow
   ```
4. Copy "npm" folder from C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules into C:\Users{YourUser}\AppData\Roaming\
5. Go to Computer -> Advanced Settings -> Environmental Variables
6. Add into User "Path" variable new entry: `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin"`
   7.Add into System "Path" variable 2 new entries:

   ```
   "C:\Users\{YourUser}\AppData\Roaming\npm"
   ```

   and

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
   ```
7. Close and open new Command Line/PowerShell terminal and run the command `npm -v`
8. If you will see version number - problem solved

Comment: but can you tell me why this has happened to me? I bought a new activated windows laptop. I didn't do any changes to it. I just installed Nodejs from the official website. I am a little curious why this problem occurred. is this problem with my Windows System or Node?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
you needed to completely remove "ComSpec" variable from your windows Environment Variable
[image]

Step2:
open shell console in mode admin and go to the directory of where your nodejs is located. In most case it is: c:\Program files\nodejs>
Step3:
install npm latest version in the nodejs file

c:\Program files\nodejs> npm install npm@latest.

That's All!

Answer (score 0):

If cmd not open,

- Go to the system environment
  [image]
- Click the environment variables
  [image]
- Go to the user variables path and click the edit
  [image]
- Click the new and add "C:\Windows\SysWOW64" and press OK.
- Then go to the folder where you want to run npm command.
- After go the folder according to this image type 'cmd' command in serach box and enter.
  [image]
- Then run your npm comannds