# npm is not working properly? 'npm.cmd' failed to run: The system cannot find the file?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, windows-11

[image]I am new to *nodejs* environment. after installing *nodejs* in my windows system I tried checking their versions.

`node -v` is showing `v16.7.0` okay.

but `npm -v` is not working.

I don't know why. I tried changing `the environmental variable` Path as well but it did not work.
below I showed the result after entering `npm -v` in my windows command promt :

```
Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: The system cannot find the file specifiedAt line:1 
char:1
+ npm -v

At line:1 char:1
+ npm -v
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

so please help me, am stuck here the whole day . pardon me if I do any mistake,Thank you :) ?

Comment: if you start a command prompt and do npm -v same results? as node cmd. if same result, when you installed node you have the option to install npm but it is not required so check to see if you have it. or just restart and install it all again

Comment: yes, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling several times. but still getting the same result.  at the time of the installation process, nodejs did not ask for any npm kind of queries to select. it has automatically been done.

Comment: try it with node 16 stable version not 18

Comment: hello @Grantmitchell, I still have the same issue :(

Comment: Did you downloaded the nodejs from its official website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution for your issue would be following these instructions.

1. Open Command Line terminal
2. Run the following command:

   DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\RepairSource\Windows /LimitAccess

After it finishes successfully run this command:

```
sfc /scannow
```

3. Copy "npm" folder from C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules into C:\Users{YourUser}\AppData\Roaming\
4. then Go to Computer -> Advanced Settings -> Environmental Variables
5. Add into User "Path" variable new entry: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin"
6. Almost there, now add into System "Path" variable 2 new entries:

"C:\Users{YourUser}\AppData\Roaming\npm"

and

"C:\Program Files\nodejs"

7. Finally run `npm-v` in a command line to verify npm is working and a version is shown.

Comment: this is based on the solution here by Sepcio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571258/npm-does-not-work-after-node-installation-program-npm-cmd-failed-to-run

Comment: Holaaa.. :D thank you @Edtimer it worked :). but can you tell me why this has happened to me? I bought a new activated windows laptop. I didn't do any changes to it. I just installed Nodejs from the official website. I am a little curious why this problem occurred. is this problem with my Windows System or Node?

Comment: I'm glad it helped! . This is related to a glitch in npm install. For a complete list of most common issues and possible fixes you can refer to this [link](https://docs.npmjs.com/common-errors#broken-npm-installation)