# How to solve npm ResourceUnavailable error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npx

I am trying to use React. I have nodejs installed and npm and npx files within that folder. I have deleted and reinstalled this folder during my current debugging process. My issue is the following error:

```
ResourceUnavailable: Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd' with working directory 'C:\Users\XXXX\projects\XXXX'. The system cannot find the file specified. At line:1 char:1
```

I receive this error regardless of directory or command involving npm or npx. Even something as simple as npm -v will cause it. Does anyone have any experience dealing with this? I am on Windows OS btw.

Tried deleting and reinstalling folder holding files. Tried multiple directories including running as admin. Tried pip installing various programs and installed other software. Googled and read numerous answers but struggled to find questions about this specific error.

Comment: You want to notice the `The system cannot find the file specified` bit meaning that the `npm.cmd` file that's supposed to be the windows npm runner literally does not exist. Reinstall node (and I'd recommend using [nvm-win](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) rather than the nodejs.org msi installer) because it did not properly install last time.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I used nvm-win like you recommended and now have the latest version of Node running. The issue is persisting so far. I did notice I have two files for npm and npx inside the node folder. Each of these includes a .cmd file that is not found and another generic file with the following:

Comment: """
#!/usr/bin/env bash
(set -o igncr) 2>/dev/null && set -o igncr; # cygwin encoding fix

basedir=`dirname "$0"`

case `uname` in
  *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

NODE_EXE="$basedir/node.exe"
if ! [ -x "$NODE_EXE" ]; then
  NODE_EXE="$basedir/node"
fi
if ! [ -x "$NODE_EXE" ]; then
  NODE_EXE=node
fi
"""
etc. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah: why are you using cygwin? If you install Node for windows, use the windows terminal emulator (it comes with both `cmd` and `powershell`). Cygwin is for when you need to fake linux/unix, which you don't even need to do anymore on windows, you have WSL available now (which, just like cygwin, you _don't need_ for anything node related).

Answer (score 0):

Posting this in case anyone else stumbles upon my question. Problem was solved by following the steps outlined below:

[NPM does not work after NODE installation. Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571258/npm-does-not-work-after-node-installation-program-npm-cmd-failed-to-run)