# npm error, 'npm.cmd' failed to run , The system cannot find the file specified At line:1 char:1 unable to find npm package in node js files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

["npm.cmd" failed to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y8xV.png)

Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: The system cannot find the file specifiedAt line:1 char:1

- npm -v
- 

At line:1 char:1

- npm -v
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
  ```

Stuck here from 3 days but unable to resolve

1. reinstall node.js many times
2. Open Command Line terminal

1.Run the following command:

2.DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\RepairSource\Windows /LimitAccess

3. After it finishes successfully run this command:

   sfc /scannow
4. Copy "npm" folder from C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules into C:\Users{YourUser}\AppData\Roaming\
5. then Go to Computer -> Advanced Settings -> Environmental Variables
6. Add into User "Path" variable new entry: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin"
7. Almost there, now add into System "Path" variable 2 new entries:

"C:\Users{YourUser}\AppData\Roaming\npm"

and

"C:\Program Files\nodejs"

8. Finally run npm-v in a command line to verify npm is working and a version is shown.

I have done above solution, but still getting the same error

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8312   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571258/npm-does-not-work-after-node-installation-program-npm-cmd-failed-to-run