npm not working while node js is working fine , dont know what is the problem
I have tried everything to run npm, installed and uninstalled node js various times still npm is not running while node js version is showing by using node -v , that is v20.18.0, but npm -v , gives the error-
Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: The system cannot find the file specifiedAt line:1 char:1
+ npm -v
+ ~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm -v
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

what to do and how to solve this npm error
tried all commands and installing again and again

Could you please check this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571258/npm-does-not-work-after-node-installation-program-npm-cmd-failed-to-run

Assuming windows based on npm.cmd.   where npm and where node are useful things to investigate at your command line.  The npm.cmd script launches node.exe from the same folder as the npm.cmd that is found.

I know maybe it's not advanced method to solve your problem but If npm is not in your system’s PATH (Windows), Node.js might be working, but npm might not.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
